# How to play music from one web page and stop it from another web page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am new to coding. I want to play some music in the background of a webpage and I want to keep it playing until I reach a page of my website.
E.g. start playing in something.com/home, keep playing if I go to something.com/about, but stop it when go to something.com/contact.

I can make the music start playing with javascript, but I can't stop it from a different page.

I have looked around and I have not found any good answer or example on this.

I have asked the same question in various places, but have not received any answer. I am not sure if I am asking the question in the wrong way, If the answer is too obvious or if it is impossible to do what I want to do.

This is what I did:

**audioPlayer.js**

```
var audioPlayer = function (fileName) {
  var audio = new Audio(require('../sounds/' + fileName))
  audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    this.currentTime = 0
    setTimeout(() => this.play(), 450)
  }, false)
  if (!!document.getElementById('contact-page') === true) {
    audio.addEventListener('playing', function () {
      this.pause()
    }, false)
  }
  audioPlayer.play()
}

export default function (fileName) {
  audioPlayer(fileName)
}
```

**home.vue**

```
<script>
import audioPlayer from '../assets/js/audio-player.js'

...

export default {
  ...
  },
  methods: {
    backgroundMusic () {
      audioPlayer('soundtrack-base.mp3')
    },
  mounted () {
      this.backgroundMusic()
  }
}
</script>
```

**contact.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="contact-page"></div>
</template>

<script>
import audioPlayer from '../assets/js/audio-player.js'

...

export default {
  ...
  },
  methods: {
    backgroundMusic () {
      audioPlayer('soundtrack-base.mp3')
    },
  mounted () {
      this.backgroundMusic()
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think better approach would be to make a base layout which includes header and footer. And you only update the body part. In that case, when you go from one page to another you are basically on the same page, so music can run until you trigger a sound stop on contact page.

Comment: It won't work. For this, you need to study synchronous request and WebSockets. Even if you load the same pages in two tabs that mean the similar source is being cloned at two places and operations performed on both of them will work in a transactional manner. Traditionally these request-response cycles are known as asynchronous requests. But you can achieve the desired behavior via using WebSockets. You will get dozen of tutorials on YouTube for WebSockets.

Comment: Thank you for the lead, I'll investigate that.